Freezing randomly. Intel with 4GB RAM
I'm really tired of freezing of linux. These freezes is on every single distro that i used. Windows do not freeze, but the perfomance is bad on it.
Tried arch-based ubuntu-based and debian distros.
Tried to fix it with chatgpt - didnt helped
I have swap so its not about swap
My device:
Asus E410MA
RAM: 4 GB; CPU; Intel Celeron N4020 (that has Intel Graphics 600); SSD 128 GB
So, some hints that i have: When i disconnect my laptop and it starts work from the battery it will freeze (after some seconds)
It can freeze when i log in to xfce4
It can freeze after i log in to xfce4 successfully, but after opening firefox it freezes.
If you will say hardware problem, then why i dont have these problems on windows?
I can take some logs. Please say which

Have you looked to see if you meet  the minimum hardware requirements for Ubuntu? https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/SystemRequirements  You might get a better result if you try a lightweight version of Ubuntu (eg Lubuntu) as your computer may not have high enough spec to run Ubuntu.

It's most likely a driver issue from what you suggest. You can try reading through the output of sudo dmesg and cat /var/log/syslog for anything that looks like it might be an error. A successful memtest86 and CPU/GPU temperatures that are satisfactory would give you more hard evidence that it's not faulty hardware

You've provided no specifics we can help with...  I use rather old hardware in QA for Ubuntu and flavors (as old as from 2005!) which of course includes devices with limited resources... and software stack is critcial; the defaults being set by install media (and you don't even mention release details; let alone ISO you used!).  For minimum RAM setting an appropriate swap matters; for GPU kernel stack matters (so consider ISO used! not just release), even kernel stack results can vary a little based on CPU (I may test all work; but they're not all identical in performance!)

The distro matters in my opinion little; as they all use the same upstream sources in the end (ie. Arch, Debian & Ubuntu you mention all use the same upstream source projects for source code) but the various components get packaged at varying times.. it's the software stack itself that matters; and your trying different distros is not a logical or systematic approach if you don't consider that actual differences between them!!  ie. I'm using Ubuntu right now, but the software is almost identical to my Debian box as oracular (Ubuntu) and trixie (Debian) are almost the same..

Ubuntu LTS releases offer kernel stack choice; stable releases are created at a specific time thus the timing is the major detail that varies (Ubuntu & Debian are both stable systems, Arch is not; Arch will be somewhat akin though to my use of development and testing for Ubuntu and Debian as I'm not using stable) and your question mixes all critical differences only giving packager teams (ie. Arch, Debian, Ubuntu...) without specifics. Consider the stack within the distro & not just the 'brand names'.  If you can get one to work; all the others will too

Can you try an even lighter OS like Raspberry Pi OS for desktop?
